# Cannot run "Create Fishnet" tool in ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.5, vector-grid, error-000735

I've been trying to run an ArcPy code which creates a fishnet for sampling.
Everything in the code works fine, but when it gets to `arcpy.CreateFishnet_management()`, it stops running.

I've already checked the documentation of ArcGIS Desktop about this function, and I don't know what I'm missing.
The error says that there is no value assigned to parameter `origin_coord` nor to `y_axis_coord`.
I've checked the documentation about this and in the part that describes `template` parameter it says:

> Specify the extent of the fishnet. The extent can be entered by specifying the coordinates or using a template dataset.

My problem is that, since I'm specifying the template to be the same as the feature, I'm leaving those parameters (`origin_coord` and `y_axis_coord`) empty, but the documentation says I could do so.

Here is the code:

```
# coding utf-8
import arcpy

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
ws = 'D:\Projeto_VANT\SIG\proc_parc.gdb'
arcpy.env.workspace = ws

arcpy.CreatePersonalGDB_management('D:\Projeto_VANT\SIG', 'output')
outpath = 'D:\Projeto_VANT\SIG\output.mdb'

talhoes = r'teste'

estados = ('SP', 'MG')
florestas = ('PROPRIA', 'PARCERIA')

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(talhoes,
                                  'talhoes_layer',
                                  """ "ESTADO" IN {} AND "FLORESTA" IN {} """.format(estados, florestas),
                                  ws)
arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(in_features = 'talhoes_layer',
                                            out_path = outpath,
                                            out_name = 'talhoes1')
talhoes1 = r'talhoes1'

arcpy.AddField_management(talhoes1, 'CONCAT_T', 'TEXT')
arcpy.CalculateField_management(talhoes1, 'CONCAT_T', """ [ESTADO] & "_" & [CODIGO] & "_" & [TALHAO] """, 'VB')

list_of_fields = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(talhoes1)]

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(talhoes1, ['CONCAT_T', 'AREA']) as tal_cursor:
    for x in tal_cursor:
        arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(talhoes1,
                                          'layer_{}'.format(x[0]),
                                          """ CONCAT_T = '{}' """.format(str(x[0])))
        arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion('layer_{}'.format(x[0]),
                                                    outpath,
                                                    'Layer_{}'.format(x[0]))
        arcpy.env.workspace = outpath
        talhao = r'Layer_{}'.format(x[0])
        arcpy.Buffer_analysis(talhao,
                              'negBuf40_{}'.format(x[0]),
                              -40)
        negBuf_tal = r'negBuf40_{}'.format(x[0])
        arcpy.CreateFishnet_management(out_feature_class = 'Fish_{}'.format(x[0]),
                                       cell_width = 22.6,
                                       cell_height = 22.6,
                                       number_rows= 0,
                                       number_columns = 0,
                                       labels = True,
                                       template = negBuf_tal,
                                       geometry_type = "POLYGON")

        print('Talhao {} succesfully extracted!'.format(x[0]))
        arcpy.env.workspace = ws
```

And here is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/ArcPy_Classes/Scripts/sampling_sig.py", line 51, in <module>
    geometry_type = "POLYGON")
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.5\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 17024, in CreateFishnet
    raise e
arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000735: Fishnet Origin Coordinate : Value is required
ERROR 000735: Y-Axis Coordinate : Value is required
Failed to execute (CreateFishnet).
```

Comment: labels = 'LABELS' for sure...check you negBuf_tal to ensure it is returning the correct text.   See here:  https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/create-fishnet.htm

Comment: In the documentation it lists the required and optional parameters.  Both `origin_coord` and `y_axis_coord` are _not_ listed as Optional.  see https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/tools/data-management-toolbox/create-fishnet.htm#GUID-2D4D98B7-5ECA-4986-98CA-827C6D824DC5

Comment: I don't understand why someone down voted this question. It seems to me I have explained everything about the problem, providing exemple of code and error. Anyway, thanks to everyone who helped or tried to help me here! =)

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I got it, but I had to calculate the extents. 
Here is the solution I got:

```
desc = arcpy.Describe(negBuf_tal)
            arcpy.CreateFishnet_management('Fish_{}'.format(x[0]),
                                           str(desc.extent.lowerLeft),
                                           str(desc.extent.XMin) + " " + str(desc.extent.YMax),
                                           22.6,
                                           22.6,
                                           0,
                                           0,
                                           str(desc.extent.upperRight),
                                           "LABELS",
                                           "#",
                                           "POLYGON")
```